# Error downloading package_esp32

Tags: esp32

I've been trying to install esp32 on Arduino IDE for days now but I keep getting 'error downloading package' message. I checked the over and over again, it's correct. I even tried installing it manually using GitGUI but it's not working. Please help me.

Comment: what's correct?

Comment: The link. I was wondering maybe I was making a mistake but I checked, there's no mistake

Comment: Describe exactly what steps you followed and any error messages you get. Otherwise we'll just have to guess. You may write "it's correct" but the fact that you can't get it to work tells me otherwise. Did you follow [these instructions](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/arduino-ide/boards_manager.md) ?

Comment: The content of the boards manager json file the ESP32 Arduino package downloads and is well formed JSON.  There appear to be 14 distinct .zip and .tar.gz files for the core and tools files for the various platforms supported by the 1.0.4 release.  All of them download for me.  You should update your question in all the ways mentioned in comments above.

Comment: *Started the IDE, opened files>preferences, entered the link, open tools>boards>boards manager, searched for esp32 but it showed blank. I tried three types which I all found on the net
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_dev_index.json

https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json
The error message I keep getting reads;
'Error downloading [the link I use]'

Comment: The last, https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json is what I believe to be correct and what I'd used when doing the work behind my prior comment.

Comment: What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: Also experiencing this issue, exactly as described by the OP. Anyone have a solution?